# Separate list in equal steps

Tags: python

I have a list of variable size. She will always have at least three elements, and new elements are always multiples of three.

An example list would be as follows:

```
['ttyUSB0', 'ttyUSB1', 'ttyUSB2', 'ttyUSB3', 'ttyUSB4',
'ttyUSB5', 'ttyUSB6', 'ttyUSB7', 'ttyUSB8']
```

My problem is I always have to pick the second element of this trio. So, for the above list, I need to recover the following result:

```
['ttyUSB1', 'ttyUSB4', 'ttyUSB7']
```

The code below works perfectly, but is not elegant, someone has some more inteigente solution?

```
def removeUselessSerialDoors(self, devices):

    new_list = []
    count = 0

    for port in devices:

        if count == 0:
            pass

        elif count == 1:
            new_list.append(port)

        elif count == 2:
            count = 0
            continue

        count = count + 1    

    return new_list
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Yep, apparently *she will always have three elements* :)

Comment: Sorry, I did my best to use their language, edit and correct the error if deemed necessary.

Comment: @Renato: Don't worry about it :)

Comment: Yes, SO appreciates people for the quality of their posts, not for the quality of their English :) *but you might not get away with it [here](http://english.stackexchange.com) :)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/10077):

```
>>> l = ['ttyUSB0', 'ttyUSB1', 'ttyUSB2', 'ttyUSB3', 'ttyUSB4', 'ttyUSB5', 'ttyUSB6', 'ttyUSB7', 'ttyUSB8']
>>> l[1::3]
['ttyUSB1', 'ttyUSB4', 'ttyUSB7']
```

The `1` in `[1::3]` gives the index to start, and the `3` gives the 'multiplier':

```
>>> lst = range(1, 10)
>>> lst[::3]
[1, 4, 7]
>>> lst[1::3]
[2, 5, 8]
>>> lst[0::3]
[1, 4, 7]
>>> lst[0::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> lst[1::2]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
>>>
```

Comment: Added more info to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>l=['ttyUSB0', 'ttyUSB1', 'ttyUSB2', 'ttyUSB3', 'ttyUSB4','ttyUSB5', 'ttyUSB6', 'ttyUSB7', 'ttyUSB8']
>>newList=[]
>>for i in range(1,len(l),3):
        newlist.append(l[i])
>>newList
   ['ttyUSB1', 'ttyUSB4', 'ttyUSB7']
```

[image]